# Run gradle task and save its return value to shell script variable

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way to run a gradle task and save it output to shell variable ?

For example lets consider a gradle task that prints module version :

```
task getVersion << {
    println '2.2.0'
}
```

I run this task in the shell like this :

```
$./gradlew getVersion
```

Is it possible to save output of gradle task **getVersion** into shell variable. For example:

```
VERSION=`./gradlew getVersion`
echo "Module Version is $VERSION"
```

Answer (score 24):

In bash, you can do it like this:

```
VERSION=$(./gradlew -q getVersion | tail -n 1)
```

`-q` : set gradle output to quit

`| tail -n 1` : only use the last line of the output in your variable. Might not need this part, but sometime gradle outputs warnings/errors before printing the actual output. I personally experienced this while upgrading to gradle4.1. After the upgrade it also showed `Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.`

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: This is what works best

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Kotlin DSL to write the task, you can do it without printing the newline. In your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks.register("getVersion") {
    doLast {
        print(project.version)
    }
}
```

And then you can execute from your terminal:

```
VERSION=$(./gradlew -q getVersion)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
exec {
    commandLine "./gradlew getVersion"
    standardOutput = output
}
VERSION =  output.toString().trim()
```

Comment: actual question is to run gradle task from a shell script